# What did Barry Allen inherit by watching the confession video?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

Here's the scene:

> Lawyer: As you know, Harrison Wells left the property to you as part of his living trust.
>   Barry: Yeah, which I did not ask him to do, but I've been keeping the place up.
>   Lawyer: Well, It's going to take more than cleaning the floors to retain it, I'm afraid. The facility and the real estate are scheduled to go into receivership at the end of this week unless you watch this.

We know Barry inherited STAR Labs and some property (see the "Hall of Justice" hangar in the Invasion Crossover event), but it's not explained is if this trust included other funds to help care for the various properties, or if the trust handles all that and he simply gets to use the places.

I don't know if we're meant to assume his inheritance from Wells included more than the lab/hangar.
**What all was included in Barry's inheritance?**

Was it only property? Were there liquid assets? Of the properties we know of, can we estimate their value?

Answer (score 1):

Barry inherited both Star Labs and the remaining money that Eobard Thawne used to keep it up and running. This is why Team Flash magically has enough money to keep the place running but low-paying jobs.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to include a relevant quote as supporting evidence. If you do add a quote, be sure to specify where it's from.

Comment: There is no specific quote stating what was inherited, although we can infer that money was a large part of the inheritance given Eobard Thawnes fortune in money, as well him saying that he has left some things behind for Barry and the team.